# Appending a Path to a Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Is it possible to append a `pathlib.Path` generator or, combine two `Path`s?

```
from pathlib import Path
paths = Path('folder_with_pdfs').glob('**/*.pdf')
paths.append(Path('folder_with_xlss').glob('**/*.xls'))
```

With this attempt you'll get:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) returns a `generator`, i.e an object that returns values when `next` is called which has absolutely no idea what `append`ing is.

You have two options here, if you require a list wrap the paths in a `list` call:

```
paths = list(Path('folder_with_pdfs').glob('**/*.pdf'))
paths.append(list(Path('folder_with_xlss').glob('**/*.xls')))
```

<sub>(Even though `extend` is probably what you're after here.)</sub>

this of course defeats the purpose of the generator.

So, I'd suggest using something like [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and creating a generator that will combine them and yield from them one at a time:

```
from itertools import chain

p1 = Path('folder_with_pdfs').glob('**/*.pdf')
p2 = Path('folder_with_xlss').glob('**/*.xls')
paths = chain(p1, p2)
```

Then iterating over `paths` as required while keeping the memory footprint down.